# Creating a new modern theme in SharePoint 2019/Subscription edition

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, 2019, sharepoint-subscription

I am trying to add a new modern theme in SharePoint subscription server

I was able to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-rest-api) and change the theme of the site with the below javascript/rest api

```
var contextResponse;
var requestDigest;
var varSiteURL="/sites/Vicky-Dev/";
function GetContext(){
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if (req.readyState != 4) // Loaded
      return;
    contextResponse = JSON.parse( req.responseText);
    requestDigest = contextResponse.FormDigestValue;
  };
  // Prepend web URL to url and remove duplicated slashes.
  var webBasedUrl = ( varSiteURL + "/_api/contextinfo").replace(/\/{2,}/,"/");
  req.open("POST",webBasedUrl,true);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
  req.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal");
  req.setRequestHeader("ODATA-VERSION","4.0");
  req.send( JSON.stringify({ "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }) );
};

function RestRequest(url,params) {
  GetContext();
  setTimeout(function() {
    
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.onreadystatechange = function ()
      {
        if (req.readyState != 4) // Loaded
          return;
        console.log(req.responseText);
      };
      // Prepend web URL to url and remove duplicated slashes.
      var webBasedUrl = ( varSiteURL + url).replace(/\/{2,}/,"/");
      req.open("POST",webBasedUrl,true);
      req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
      req.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal");
      req.setRequestHeader("x-requestdigest", requestDigest);
      req.setRequestHeader("ODATA-VERSION","4.0");
      req.send(params ? JSON.stringify(params) : void 0);
      },2000);
}


var pal = {
    "palette" : {
              "themePrimary": "#1B325F",
              "themeLighterAlt": "#f1f4f9",
              "themeLighter": "#cbd4e5",
              "themeLight": "#a2b1cf",
              "themeTertiary": "#5a719f",
              "themeSecondary": "#2a4272",
              "themeDarkAlt": "#182c55",
              "themeDark": "#142548",
              "themeDarker": "#0f1b35",
              "neutralLighterAlt": "#f8f8f8",
              "neutralLighter": "#f4f4f4",
              "neutralLight": "#eaeaea",
              "neutralQuaternaryAlt": "#dadada",
              "neutralQuaternary": "#d0d0d0",
              "neutralTertiaryAlt": "#c8c8c8",
              "neutralTertiary": "#b4b4b4",
              "neutralSecondary": "#9b9b9b",
              "neutralPrimaryAlt": "#838383",
              "neutralPrimary": "#222222",
              "neutralDark": "#525252",
              "black": "#3a3a3a",
              "white": "#ffffff"
            }
}
RestRequest("/_api/thememanager/AddTenantTheme", {name:"Sounders Rave Green", themeJson: JSON.stringify(pal)});

RestRequest("/_api/thememanager/ApplyTheme", {name:"Sounders Rave Green", themeJson: JSON.stringify(pal)});
```

This is creating a new folder in the themed folder, but I don't see the theme name under the change the look option

[image]

[image]

If I create a new entry in the composed looks `/_catalogs/design/`, I see that option only in classic option.

Is there a way to create a new theme so that it shows up under "Change the look"?

Answer (score 1):

See: [SPO Modern Site Custom Theme](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268053/spo-modern-site-custom-theme)

Are you a tenant administrator? You can use PowerShell to `Add-PnpTenantTheme` and `Set-PnPWebTheme`

Code snippet @Denis Molodtsov:

```
$themeHash = @{
    "themePrimary" = "#0078d4";
    "themeLighterAlt" = "#f3f9fd";
    "themeLighter" = "#d0e7f8";
    "themeLight" = "#a9d3f2";
    "themeTertiary" = "#5ca9e5";
    "themeSecondary" = "#1a86d9";
    "themeDarkAlt" = "#006cbe";
    "themeDark" = "#005ba1";
    "themeDarker" = "#004377";
    "neutralLighterAlt" = "#f8f8f8";
    "neutralLighter" = "#f4f4f4";
    "neutralLight" = "#eaeaea";
    "neutralQuaternaryAlt" = "#dadada";
    "neutralQuaternary" = "#d0d0d0";
    "neutralTertiaryAlt" = "#c8c8c8";
    "neutralTertiary" = "#bab8b7";
    "neutralSecondary" = "#a3a2a0";
    "neutralPrimaryAlt" = "#8d8b8a";
    "neutralPrimary" = "#323130";
    "neutralDark" = "#605e5d";
    "black" = "#494847";
    "white" = "#ffffff";
}

Add-PnPTenantTheme -Identity "Corporate Theme" -Palette $themeHash -IsInverted $false -Overwrite

# Apply theme to the root web of the site collection
Set-PnPWebTheme -Theme "Corporate Theme" -WebUrl $TargetSiteUrl

# Apply theme to all subsites recursively
Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse | % {Set-PnPWebTheme -Theme "Corporate Theme" -Web $_}
```